# Apache Camel - property, header or something else to know that specific route is done file processing

Tags: apache-camel

I have an typical task to Apache Camel:

```
from(properties.get(EVN.getFolderProperty()))
    .onCompletion()
        .log("Done")
        .end()
    .log("Start")
    .split().tokenizeXML("Test")
        .streaming()
    .bean(xmlProcessor, "processOneRecord")
    .aggregate(exchangeProperty("Some key"), xmlAggregationStrategy).copletionSize(100)
    .bean(resultProcessor, "appendToResult");
```

so I want not to use one of simple Completion strategy - timeout, size.
Instead - I need some status variable, header, property to use in somthng like that:

```
        .aggregate(exchangeProperty("Some key"), xmlAggregationStrategy).completionPredicate("routeIsFinishFileProcessing" == true)
    .bean(resultProcessor, "appendToResult");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `simple` expression, `.completionPredicate(simple("${property.routeIsFinishFileProcessing == true}")`

Note : you must take care of setting the `property.routeIsFinishFileProcessing` to true whenever you want it to complete